# How to play m3u8 link

Tags: raspbian, networking, streaming-video

How to open player on automatics some m3u8 URL
for example:

http://192.168.1.99/atc/videourl.m3u8

When raspberry pi open then start player full screen and open this URL.

I am using raspi little

Comment: Please consider formatting and extending your question. As it is now, it is not very easy to understand what you want, what you tried and how the result differed from the expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try using crontab. For example: `@reboot omxplayer /path/to/movie/file/here/movie.m3u8`. I don't know if this will work, but if it doesn't, you can remove it from crontab anytime.